# Python: itertools.islice not working in a loop

Tags: python, file-io, python-itertools

I have code like this:

```
#opened file f
goto_line = num_lines #Total number of lines
while not found:
   line_str = next(itertools.islice(f, goto_line - 1, goto_line))
   goto_line = goto_line/2
   #checks for data, sets found to True if needed
```

line_str is correct the first pass, but every pass after that is reading a different line then it should.

So for example, goto_line starts off as 1000. It reads line 1000 just fine. Then the next loop, goto_line is 500 but it doesn't read line 500. It reads some line closer to 1000.

I'm trying to read specific lines in a large file without reading more than necessary. Sometimes it jumps backwards to a line and sometimes forward.

I did try linecache, but I typically don't run this code more than once on the same file.

Comment: What lines does it read and what lines do you expect it to read? (Also: Please indent more deeply - say, 4 spaces - it's hard to read this way.)

Comment: For what I'm using, it is told to read line 4382898 and does it correctly on the first pass. Then goto_line changes to 2191449 but then islice returns around line 6574286.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python iterators can be consumed only once.  This is easiest seen by example.  The following code

```
from itertools import islice
a = range(10)
i = iter(a)
print list(islice(i, 1, 3))
print list(islice(i, 1, 3))
print list(islice(i, 1, 3))
print list(islice(i, 1, 3))
```

prints

```
[1, 2]
[4, 5]
[7, 8]
[]
```

The slicing always starts where we stopped last time.

The easiest way to make your code work is to use the `f.readlines()` to get a list of the lines in the file and then use normal Python list slicing `[i:j]`.  If you really want to use `islice()`, you could start reading the file from the beginning each time by using `f.seek(0)`, but this will be very inefficient.

Comment: I don't want to read more than necessary, it's a very large file. Hoping to be efficient here, not elegant.

Comment: @Zeno: It's impossible to find a line in a text file by line number without reading all the preceding lines, because the lines have different lengths.

Comment: "Python iterators can be consumed only once" does answer my question though, thanks.

Comment: What's happening when `islice` asks for the 1000th line of the file, is that the file object reads all the way through the file line-by-line until it finds the 1000th line. It doesn't jump past the first 999; it has to read them all. It seems fast because 1000 lines isn't really that many, but if you had a file with a million lines, it would become very slow. If you're dealing with files that big, and you need to seek into the middle of them without reading the whole thing, then you need to use real database software like SQLite. You *really* don't want to solve that problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (this way - perhaps there is some way depending on how the file is opened) go back in the file. The standard file iterator (in fact, most iterators - Python's iterator protocol only supports forward iterators) moves *only* forward. So after reading `k` lines, reading another `k/2` lines actually gives the `k+k/2`th line.

You *could* try reading the whole file into memory, but you have a lot of data so memory consumption propably becomes an issue. You could use `file.seek` to scroll through the file. But that's still a lot of work - perhaps you could use a [memory-mapped file](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html)? That's only possible if lines are fixed-size though. If it's necessary, you could pre-calculate the line numbers you'd like to check and save all those lines (shouldn't be too much, roughly `int(log_2(line_count)) + 1` if I'm not mistaken) in one iteration so you don't have to scroll back after reading the whole file.

Comment: Yeah, it's a huge file which is why I'm using islice and not readlines.

Comment: mmap probably won't work anyway because it's a 32bit OS and so it can only read the first 4GB.

Comment: @Zeno: And what about the last proposed solution (iterating once and storing all lines you may need)?