# Using Continue Statement in nested for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, continue, readfile

Hi I have a function that read in data from two files.  What I want to be happening is that the outer loop starts to read in the the first file and if lum from the first file is greater than the defined value (LC) the loop skips to the next iteration. If not the code moves to the
inner loop which reads in the hlist and builds the x,y,z lists if idc and id are the same. If  idc and id are not the same value it skips to the next iteration of the inner loop. When I print test statments It seems as if the inner loop is not iterating and its not clear to me why. I would appreciate any help

Code

```
def read_file(F):      #Function that reads data froma file #and extracts specific data columns
    X_pos = []
    Y_pos = []                # Creats Data Lists
    Z_pos = []
    Idh = []
    Id = []
    LC = float(sys.argv[1]) 
    N = 11#912639            # number of lines to be read
    Nl = 11#896030
    fl = open(Fl)            #opens catalog file
    fl.readline()
    nlines_catalog = islice(fl, Nl)
    f = open(F)           #Opens hlist file
    f.readline()          # Strips Header
    nlines_hlist = islice(f, N) #slices file to only read N lines

    for linel in nlines_catalog:
            if linel != '':
              linel = linel.strip()              
              linel = linel.replace('\t', '')
              columnsl = linel.split()
              lum = float(columnsl[1])
              id_catalog = int(columnsl[0])
              if lum >= LC:
                 continue
              print("lum1 =", lum)
              #Id.append(idc)
              print("id_catalog=", id_catalog)
              for line in nlines_hlist:
                 if line != '':
                    line = line.strip()
                    line = line.replace('\t', ' ')
                    columns = line.split()
                    id_hlist = int(columns[1])
                    #Idh.append(id)
                     if id_hlist != id_ccatalog:
                        continue
                    print('idc =', idc, 'id =', id)
                    x = columns[17]           
                    y = columns[18]
                    z = columns[19]
                    X_pos.append(x)
                    Y_pos.append(y)                #appends data in list
                    Z_pos.append(z)

    print(X)
    X = [float(p) for p in X_pos]        
    Y = [float(p) for p in Y_pos]
    Z = [float(p) for p in Z_pos]
    Xa = numpy.array(X, dtype=float)
    Ya = numpy.array(Y, dtype=float)
    Za = numpy.array(Z, dtype=float)


    return(Xa, Ya, Za)
```

**EDIT**

Changes to inner loop that allow it to reset and now work.

```
 if id_catalog ==  id_halo:
      print('id_catalog =',id_catalog,'id_halo =',id_halo)
      x = columns[17]             # assigns variable to columns
      y = columns[18]
      z = columns[19]
      #vx = columns[]
      #vy = columns[]
      #vz = columns[]
      X_pos.append(x)
      Y_pos.append(y)                #appends data in list
      Z_pos.append(z)
      break
```

**Edit**
 I could not reproduce my original out put from the print statements, and have edited to reflect that fact

```
VirtualBox:~$ python /home/Astrophysics/Count_FixedLoop.py -21.5 125
('lum1 =', -21.78545)
('idc=', 2701276876L)
('idc =', 2701276876L, 'id =', 2701276876L)
('lum1 =', -21.69835)
('idc=', 2699751347L)
('lum1 =', -21.69942)
('idc=', 2699724518L)
('lum1 =', -21.74543)
('idc=', 2699724331L)
('lum1 =', -21.60912)
('idc=', 2699724726L)
('lum1 =', -21.53862)
('idc=', 2699725014L)
('lum1 =', -21.53155)
('idc=', 2701277269L)
['34.57223']
```

This is what I expect as output

```
 ('lum1 =', -21.78545)
 ('idc=', 2701276876L)
 ('idc =', 2701276876L, 'id =', 2701276876L)
 ('lum1 =', -21.69835)
 ('idc=', 2699751347L)
 ('idc =', 2699751347L, 'id =', 2699751347L)
 ('lum1 =', -21.69942)
 ('idc=', 2699724518L)
 ('idc =', 2699724518L, 'id =', 2699724518L)
 ('lum1 =', -21.74543)
 ('idc=', 2699724331L)
 ('idc =', 2699724331L, 'id =', 2699724331L)
 ('lum1 =', -21.60912)
 ('idc=', 2699724726L)
 ('idc =', 2699724726L, 'id =', 2699724726L)
 ('lum1 =', -21.53862)
 ('idc=', 2699725014L)
 ('idc =', 2699725014L, 'id =', 2699725014L)
 ('lum1 =', -21.53155)
 ('idc=', 2701277269L)
```

**Edit**

Sample of a few lines of the Fl file where the idc numbers are column[0] and lum values are column[1]. I have put in bold print the idc values that meet the condition in the first loop.

```
Format: ID, scatter = 0 0.05 0.1 0.13 0.15 0.16 0.18 0.2 0.25 0.3
**2701276876 -21.78545** -21.73791 -21.68872 -21.11125 -20.88102 -22.04709 -21.41715       -20.56944 -20.36757 -19.69895
**2699751347 -21.69835** -21.67935 -21.92425 -21.03465 -21.56561 -21.42124 -21.72893 -20.78131 -20.76342 -20.34830
**2699724518 -21.69942** -21.58352 -21.71149 -21.16240 -21.18507 -22.00277 -21.81500 -20.36141 -20.78227 -20.65697
```

**Edit**

Sample lines of the F file with the id's and corresponding  positions that match the first file

```
#Scale(0) Id(1) Desc_scale(2) Descid(3) Num_prog(4) Pid(5) Upid(6) Desc_pid(7)   Phantom(8) Mvir(9) Orig_Mvir(10) Rvir(11) Rs(12) Vrms(13) Mmp(14) Last_mm(15) Vmax(16) X(17) Y(18) Z(19) 
 0.9523 **2701276876** 0.9583 2714557311      1       -1       -1       -1  0     3.56533e+13 3.56100e+13 695.459000 80.562000 548.820000  1 0.3603 561.490000 **34.57223 140.20813 130.81985** -110.000 323.430 -123.520 3.56533e+13 3.56533e+13 561.490000 599.410000 7.539e+14 -3.799e+12 -1.992e+14 0.10259
0.9523 **2699751347** 0.9583 2713034575      4       -1       -1       -1  0 3.36604e+13 3.31300e+13 678.981000 111.199000 500.400000  1 0.8083 514.010000 **28.70439 138.70247 138.52176** -215.310 252.520 -120.970 3.36604e+13 3.36604e+13 514.010000 599.250000 5.516e+14 1.044e+14 6.133e+14 0.10973
0.9523 **2699724518** 0.9583 2713007786      1       -1       -1       -1  0 2.98000e+13 2.97500e+13 654.997000 87.324000 457.460000  1 0.4863 514.660000 **8.01627 135.31783 123.13322** -178.990 558.900 1.250 2.98000e+13 2.98000e+13 514.660000 514.660000 8.529e+14 2.711e+14 -3.624e+14 0.15137
```

What I am expecting is that when the id's from both files match the second loop will append the X,Y, and Z position lists. So printing the list in this example will give

```
X = [34.57223,28.70439,8.01627]
Y = [140.20813,138.70247,135.31783]
Z = [130.81985,138.52176,123.13322]
```

Comment: Can we see the code for Count_FixedLoop.py? Or at least the part where read_file is called?

Comment: This code sample is somewhat hard to follow. Perhaps we can help better if you show some lines from the input files and tell what us you want to accomplish.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python multi-loop failed when with generator and iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290951/python-multi-loop-failed-when-with-generator-and-iterator)

Comment: As noted, it would help to see your data files to understand your intent, but on cursory examination: check the indent levels of all statements in those loops. It appears that if there is an empty `linel` you still execute the inner loop - is this desired? It also appears that you will try to extract data from an empty `line` in the inner loop because you didn't indent all the rest of the statements after if `line != '':`

Comment: Are you sure that output is for that code? I can't see what would print idc= (rather than 'idc =') in the code you've provided. In general, for problems like this finding a minimal test case can be helpful (http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code gives some advice on constructing such things). In your specific case, I would look closely at your F file: how many entries does it have? Are they space-separated like you need them to be? How far through Fl do you have to go before you find an idc that will match F's second line? But constructing a minimal test case is the way to go.

Comment: ... Has everyone else missed the use of `islice()`?

Comment: @David I will post up the code when I get home

Comment: @Paulo I will post a few lines of the input tomorrow

Comment: @ Keith the indentation are typos I will fix now

Comment: Whatever happened to meaningful variable names? Also, this is Python. You don't need to initialize variables or delete variables. And indentation really, really matters.

Comment: @ Joel I was  deleting the lists after the array creation to free up memory . Can you suggest where and how I can fix the indentation? I will rethink the variable names. Thank you.

Comment: Also there are no empty lines in either data file and both files are roughly 11 million lines, but I limited them to 11 lines to test. In my test there are 7 lum's that are less than LC so there should be 7 idc's from the first file that have matching id's in the second file.

Comment: @PauloScardine I added input and what I want to have the code do

Comment: This code cannot generate your output. There is a IndentationError.

Comment: Fixed the indentation error which happened when I copy and pasted the code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be expecting `nlines` to behave like a *list*. However, it is instead an [*iterator*](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), and as Ignacio pointed out above, it will be consumed *once*. In other words, the inner loop doesn't get "reset" to the first line/index on subsequent outer loop executions.

Consider the following analog (I think) to what you're doing. Here are two data files:

Data1:

```
file 1: one
file 1: two
file 1: three
file 1: four
file 1: five
```

Data2:

```
file 2: one
file 2: two
file 2: three
file 2: four
file 2: five
file 2: six
```

Running this:

```
from itertools import islice

f1 = open ("Data1")
f2 = open ("Data2")

iterator1 = islice (f1, 3)
iterator2 = islice (f2, 3)

for line1 in iterator1:
    print line1

    for line2 in iterator2:
       print line2
```

results in:

```
file 1: one
file 2: one
file 2: two
file 2: three
file 1: two
file 1: three
```

whereas one might erroneously expect that 3 lines of the contents of `data2` would be printed for each of the first 3  lines of `data1`.

So, the first execution of the inner loop fully *consumes* `iterator2`. In your own code there is no inner loop break when `id == idc` - in other words, you consume interator `nlines` completely the first time that inner loop executes.

See also, [Python: itertools.islice not working in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020444/python-itertools-islice-not-working-in-a-loop) for another example.

One solution may be to break in the inner loop when `id == idc`, but this will assume (I think) an ordering of indices in your second file. You could consider actually using a list for the inner loop, although that seems memory-intensive given the size of your actual (non-test) data. You could obviously reread that second file, although performance will take a hit.

Comment: Keith you are correct in my misunderstanding of the behavior of nlines. I did assume that the inner loop would reset each time the outer loop was executed.

Comment: I did as you suggested and changed the continue to break and it now works perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: I have also edited the question with the changes if anyone else has a similar problem

Comment: Keith, I am I correct in my understanding that if I would have used ``nlines_hlist =  f:`` qnd not  ``nlines_hlist = islice(f, N):`` the inner loop would have reset after each time the outer loop executed?

Comment: No. `f` is a [file object, which serves in effect as its own iterator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) (ie it has a `.next()` method). I think you would be able to "reset" using something like `f.seek(0); f.readline()` immediately before the start of the inner loop, which could just be rewritten `for line in f:`This is basically what I meant when I said you could reread that second file...you could also just open and close it repeatedly.

Comment: Sorry for my un clarity I meant ''nlines_hlist =  f '' then as you said use for ''for line in nlines_hlist : ''