# Python for loop unreasonably stops half way while iterating through CSV rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, for-loop

I am dealing with a CSV file to analysis lecture feedback data, the format is like

```
"5631","18650","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:35:11"
"18650","null","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:37:12"
"18650","5631","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:37:19"
"58649","null","6",,,"2015-09-18 09:38:13"
"45379","31541","10","its friday","nothing yet keep it up","2015-09-18 09:39:46"
```

I am trying to get rid of bad data. Only the data entries with "id1","id2" **AND**  another corresponding "id2","id1" are considered valid.

I am using nested loops to try find a matching entry for each row. However, the outer loop seems to stop half way for no reason. Here's my code

```
class Filter:
    file1 = open('EncodedPeerInteractions.FA2015.csv')
    peerinter = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',') 
    def __init__(self):
        super()

    def filter(self):
        file2 = open('FilteredInteractions.csv','a')
        for row in self.peerinter:
            print(row)
            if row[0] == 'null' or row[1] == 'null':
                continue
            id1 = int(row[0])
            id2 = int(row[1])
            for test in self.peerinter:
                if test[0] == 'null' or test[1] == 'null':
                    continue
                if int(test[0]) == id2 and int(test[1]) == id1:
                    file2.write("\n")
                    file2.write(str(row))
                    break
        file2.close()
```

I have tried to use pdb to step trough the code, everything was fine for the first couple loops and then just suddenly jump to file2.close() and return. The program do prints out a few valid entries but is way not enough.

I tested the csv file and its loaded into memory properly with over 18000 entries. I tested using print but it gives the same result so its nothing wrong with the append file.

**Edit**

Now I understand what the problem is. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605346/using-continue-statement-in-nested-for-loop-in-python) says, I break out when there's a match but when there's no match, the inner loop will consume all the file without resetting it. When it return to the outer loop it simply ends. I should make it into a list or let it reset.

Comment: Quick question, why are you using a class for this and calling `super()`?  Are you using `python 3`?

Comment: I honestly don't know.. Some one told me its bad to have logic plain in files. They should be encapsulated in classes and it feels weird to put a pass there. What do you suggest me to do?

Comment: Related to the above question - what is the parent of your `Filter` class? Don't do this `file1 = open('EncodedPeerInteractions.FA2015.csv')`, do `with open('EncodedPeerInteractions.FA2015.csv',"r") as file1` for safety.

Comment: @Bobby it's OK to write **scripts**, that simply do stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Continue Statement in nested for loop in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605346/using-continue-statement-in-nested-for-loop-in-python)

Comment: @Bobby: your code here is not object oriented; putting this in a class makes no sense here.

Comment: @Bobby, So in your example above, only `"45379","31541","10","its friday","nothing yet keep it up","2015-09-18 09:39:46"` would be considered valid?

Comment: @flybonzai no, the small example   
`"5631","18650","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:35:11"`
`"18650","5631","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:37:19"`
is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this way more complicated that it needs to be.

Given:

```
$ cat /tmp/so.csv
"5631","18650","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:35:11"
"18650","null","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:37:12"
"18650","5631","10",,,"2015-09-18 09:37:19"
"58649","null","6",,,"2015-09-18 09:38:13"
"45379","31541","10","its friday","nothing yet keep it up","2015-09-18 09:39:46"
```

You can use csv and filter to get what you want:

```
>>> with open('/tmp/so.csv') as f:
...    list(filter(lambda row: 'null' not in row[0:2], csv.reader(f)))
... 
[['5631', '18650', '10', '', '', '2015-09-18 09:35:11'], 
 ['18650', '5631', '10', '', '', '2015-09-18 09:37:19'], 
 ['45379', '31541', '10', 'its friday', 'nothing yet keep it up', '2015-09-18 09:39:46']]
```

Comment: I think this method is just getting rid of null values, if a entry say 
`'123,','234',x,x,x` has no corresponding 
`'234','123',y,y,y` is also considered invalid

Comment: Then rewrite the `lambda` as a test function that tests your conditions on each row...

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like the following:

```
def filter(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
      peerinter = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=',') 
      with open(file2, 'a') as f2:
        for row in peerinter:
        ...
```

Using the `with open()` syntax wraps it in a context manager, which will ensure that the file is closed properly at the end.  I'm guessing that your problem stems from the fact you are opening one file as a class variable, and the other inside the method.